# Access violation exception when using socketio-client-c++ and boost asio io_service

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, socket.io, boost-asio

I'm trying to use io_service from boost asio library (1.61) with socketio-client-c++, but my code throws an access violation exception, and after hours of debugging I could'nt figure out what is the cause. The exception is thrown at the following location in win_mutex.hpp:

```
void lock()
{
 -> ::EnterCriticalSection(&crit_section_);
}
```

The code is very simple:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    auto io_service_work = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>      (io_service);

    sio::client client_;
    client_.connect("http://localhost:1337");

    // io_service.run();
}
```

I want to use io_service from main, and socketio also uses an io_service internally, which might be the cause of the problem.

You can download the full project with socketio source <strike>and binary</strike> included here: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/7f1afa6a-883f-4941-8371-31ccbd8514a5/socket-io.zip ¹

Any suggestion?

¹ link redacted; links (was 88M, now 443k)

Comment: Code given works for me (of course, nothing listens on port 1337): http://paste.ubuntu.com/23245787/

Answer (score 1):

Because the line simply calls a public Win32 API with *the address of something*, all that could cause this to occur is when `this` is pointing at  random something (e.g. a destructed `win_mutex`, something else, protected memory or even nullptr).

This indicates [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). UB has a gazillion possible sources, and your code is not enough to draw any conclusions. But in Asio, 99% of the time it is caused by not keeping the objects around long enough for the asynchronous operations on it to complete.

Comment: (still looking at the reduced zip now)

Answer (score 1):

I have converted the socketio project to Dll, turned off boost auto link, and manually added libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib as additional dependency. Then the code works as intended.

However, if I switch back the socketio project to static library, then the same symptom occurs as described in the question.

Please check the Dll based project files here:
http://ginf.hu/socketio/socketiotest.zip

Comment: oh - interesting stuff. Here's my Linux based test btw: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/d9f48fb5-6054-495f-a752-6531f8a3d058/linux-sioclient.zip (using a Makefile; `apt-get install build-essential make rapidjson-dev libboost-all-dev libwebsocketpp-dev; make && ./test`)

Comment: I suspect this is a windows only issue, something with boost auto link, or static and dynamic library linking.

Comment: No doubt :). @Blz

Comment: Getting closer to the source of the issue, it seems that an if condition evaluated differently in the static-lib version than in the dll version.

You can find a more detailed description and investigation here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772075/socketio-c-static-lib-compilation-results-in-entercriticalsection-exception-d