# Boost Asio if condition evaluated differently in static-lib and dll compilations, former resulting in exception in socket io cpp client lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, socket.io, boost-asio, critical-section

Depending on how the socketio c++ library is compiled (static-lib or dll) for the following simple test code, the outcome is either a working executable or one that throws an exception.

However, if the instantiation of the io_service is commented out, eg.:

> // boost::asio::io_service io_service;

then the static-lib based version is also working without exception. It seems that there is some interference between the io_service instantiated in main() with the io_service located in the socketIO library.

```
#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB

#include "../socketio/src/sio_client.h"
#include <boost\asio\io_service.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    //auto io_service_work = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io_service);
    sio::client client_;
    client_.connect("http://localhost:1337");
    //io_service.run();
}
```

Although the full source code is the same (not counting the optional conditional compilation differences), the evaluation of the following line results TRUE in the static-lib and FALSE in the Dll version:

> if (!::PostQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp_.handle, 0, 0, op))

Check the full code from win_iocp_io_service.ipp

```
void win_iocp_io_service::post_deferred_completion(win_iocp_operation* op)
{
  // Flag the operation as ready.
  op->ready_ = 1;

  // Enqueue the operation on the I/O completion port.
  if (!::PostQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp_.handle, 0, 0, op)) // DIFFERENT RESULT IN STATIC-LIB AND DLL
  {
    // Out of resources. Put on completed queue instead.
    mutex::scoped_lock lock(dispatch_mutex_);
    completed_ops_.push(op);
    ::InterlockedExchange(&dispatch_required_, 1);
  }
}
```

Please find a test package with two almost identical VS2015 solutions. Both solutions contain 2 projects (siotest and socketio). The package should be self-contained, so no additional libraries are needed to compile and test (thus the somewhat bigger size of the zip file).

[Zip file containing the test package](http://www.ginf.hu/testpkg.zip)

Socketio is a library encompassing the open source c++11 socket.io client implementation from

[Socket IO C++11 Client Implementation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp)

Siotest is a simple test program, that would connect to a socketIO server.

Both Socketio and Siotest use boost asio ioservice, although the instantiated io_service variable in Siotest is not in use after the instantiation.

In the test case that was used for demonstrating the issue, there is no listening socketio server, so the expected behavior is Connection failed messages as shown in the following screenshot, because the client cannot connect to any server.

[image: Software package containing static lib and dll versions]

This output is the result of the siotest_dll solution, which is considered to be the expected behavior for the executable.

Another version of the solution in the siotest lib folder is almost entirely identical, but the linking of the socketio project is static library as opposed to dynamic linked library in the siotest dll.

The result of the erroneous socketio_lib run is shown in the screencap below
[image: Exception]

Debugging the two versions, it seems that when compiled in Dll mode, a new thread is created for socketio's internal io_service, but no new thread is created in the static lib version, because before creating the new thread, the static-lib version throws an exception.

There is clearly some difference between the two versions of the software, although the source code is exactly the same. The example is a simplification of our software framework in which we would like to use both the socket IO client C++ library and Boost Asio IO Service.

We would like to understand the source of the issue, and be able to compile our code as static library. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't try to reason about Undefined Behaviour. It leads to nothing. Linking incompatible version of libraries violates ODR rules. Don't do that. Fix the compiler/linker flags to be compatible

Comment: Which libraries in this case are incompatible in your opinion?

Comment: Let's not make it about opinions. Reliable interop with C++ libraries requires matching ABI. In practice, the way to achieve it is to match the compiler version and flags (architecture, exceptions etc) exactly to the ones with which the library you wish to link have been built. This is, unsurprisingly, the reason why open-source libraries shine (because you can built the library yourself) and also why linux distros have a "blessed" toolchain and options which is used for their entire package repository and gets upgraded only across the board.

Comment: The top results when you google for "abi odr compatible binary c++" are pretty helpful if you want more background.

Comment: I am aware of the ABI compatibility requirements, and looked over and back for a mismatching compilation or linker setting before I posted to stackoverflow.

To make it sure, I added two additional solutions to the testpkg.zip.

Siotest_src contains the boost_system library source, and no external compiled source is used (although the previously used boost lib was also compiled by myself with the same compiler).

Siotest_sprj has the same source files and no external library dependence, but everything is packed into a single project.

Comment: As expected, Siotest_sprj works well (just as the dll version). The Siotest_src produces the same issue as described in the question, although the same compilation settings are used for all 3 projects (I tried with /MDd and /MTd settings).

Compiler and linker settings are in the corresponding solution directories, under flag_*.txt name.

Comment: @sehe

When the socketio project is compiled to a separate DLL -> OK,
together with the other sources in a single project -> OK, 
separately into a static library -> ERROR.

I am fairly sure that the comp and link flags are ok.

When compiling to DLL, only a fraction of the methods and variables are exported, and much of the stuff remains 'hidden' to the other projects.

When we use boost::asio for the socketio io_service, and the think-async non-boost asio for our own io_service, then even the static-lib version works.

Comment: Sounds like using non-boost asio just happens to fix the ODR violation.

Comment: @sehe yes, it fixes it, but what causes it remains to be seen.

Comment: "and no external compiled source is used" - check with dependency viewer, and google `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` - if you hadn't already (you don't mention it)

Comment: @sehe still no success in finding the cause of the issue. I posted a new test package to the socketio cpp site, as it seems to be some socketio lib related problem.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/issues/120

I used BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB to prevent auto linking boost. Nevertheless in the last example solutions, all required boost libs were compiled from source, and no external lib was used.

Comment: @sehe Someone at the socketio lib github page writes this:

"The dependencies to rapidjson, websocket and boost is what has been crippled me the most. If this framework didn't have any dependencies it would be so much easier to integrate. These dependencies will also theoretically create duplicate symbols for some if they also have a dependency to boost, websocket or rapidjson from other projects."

Maybe the issue is a result of some duplicate symbol?