# Access violation exception when using Boost Asio from a static library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a static library, that uses the Boost Asio lib (version 1.61.0.). This library has a Client class with the following constructor:

```
Client::Client(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service_prm, std::string host_prm, int port_prm) : io_service_(io_service_prm), host_(host_prm), port_(port_prm)
{
    socket_ = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(*io_service_);
}
```

And has some callback methods, and an init() method:

```
int Client::init() {
   resolver_ = std::make_shared <boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver>(*io_service_);
   resolver_->async_resolve({ host_, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(port_) }, std::bind(&Client::resolveHandler, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));

   return 0;
}
```

When I link against this library in a test program, and instantiate a Client, then call it's init method, the program throws an access violation exception at the following location in Boost (win_mutex.cpp, line 50):

```
// Lock the mutex.
void lock()
{
--> ::EnterCriticalSection(&crit_section_);
}
```

Here is the code of the main function:

```
int main()
{
    auto io_service = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>();
    auto worker = boost::asio::io_service::work(*io_service);
    auto host = "localhost";
    auto port = 8181;
    Client client(io_service, host, port);

    client.init();

    io_service->run();

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile the Client code directly to the executable, the problem doesn't occur.

Can anyone tell me how to properly use Boost Asio library in this scenario? The program must run on Windows, so I would greatly appreciate solutions for this OS.

You can download the source and the VS2015 solution here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByS95lLWpDcQeTYtSGdmLXVoTGc

Comment: please edit your question to include a [MCVE], that is code one can copy, paste and compile without any further modification. your question is also missing important details: (1) where exactly is the access violation occuring? (2) which boost version are you using? (3) does the problem also occur if `Client` is not in a static library but compiled directly into the executable?

Comment: your issue seems to be similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772075/boost-asio-if-condition-evaluated-differently-in-static-lib-and-dll-compilations

Answer (score 2):

Solved by including 'targetver.h' in 'Client.h' header file of the static library. This file is autogenerated if you check Precompiled headers when creating a Visual Studio project.